# Editing a config file in linux using sed command

Tags: linux, sed, config

Here, vanity is a variable and I need to place the content of this variable at the end of the line starting with the first occurrence of word "members" using sed command

```
#!/bin/bash
vanity=$()
```

testing.txt file consists of the following information :

```
define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name  NA-servers ; The name of the hostgroup
        alias           NA region ; Long name of the group
        members         abc.com,def.com,ghi.com,jkl.com
        }

define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name  SA-servers ; The name of the hostgroup
        alias           SA region ; Long name of the group
        members         abcd.com,defg.com,ghij.com,jklm.com
        }
```

I have tried this command :

```
sed "1,/members/s/$/,$vanity/" testing.txt
```

but it returns the following output :

```
define hostgroup{,mno.com
        hostgroup_name  NA-servers ; The name of the hostgroup,mno.com
        alias           NA region ; Long name of the group,mno.com
        members         abc.com,def.com,ghi.com,jkl.com,mno.com
        }
```

Required output :

```
define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name  NA-servers ; The name of the hostgroup
        alias           NA region ; Long name of the group
        members         abc.com,def.com,ghi.com,jkl.com**,mno.com**
        }

define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name  SA-servers ; The name of the hostgroup
        alias           SA region ; Long name of the group
        members         abcd.com,defg.com,ghij.com,jklm.com
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/NA-servers/,/}/{s/members.*/&,mno.com/}' file
```

Output:

```
define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name  NA-servers ; The name of the hostgroup
        alias           NA region ; Long name of the group
        members         abc.com,def.com,ghi.com,jkl.com,mno.com
        }

define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name  SA-servers ; The name of the hostgroup
        alias           SA region ; Long name of the group
        members         abcd.com,defg.com,ghij.com,jklm.com
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with GNU sed to append value only to the first occurrence:

```
sed '0,/members.*/{s//&'"$vanity"'/;}' file
```

If you don't have GNU sed installed, try this POSIX compliant one:

```
sed '1,/members.*/{s/members.*/&'"$vanity"'/;}' file
```